# Allow CORS in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cors, rails-api

In my `config/application.rb` file, I have this code,

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE'
    }
```

But that does not allow me to send a post request to a route on my sever

Safari gives this error:

```
http://localhost:3000/studentsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/studentsFailed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
localhost:1XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/students. Origin http://localhost:4200 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origi
```

And in my Rails server console:

```
Started OPTIONS "/students" for ::1 at 2015-03-28 21:00:45 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/students"):
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I spent some time working on this and I can tell you the most reliable solution is to use rack-cors. see: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

First add the gem:

```rb
gem 'rack-cors', '~> 0.3.1'
```

then in `application.rb` add

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

If your production app does not serve static assets (such as if you use a serve like nginx or apache), consider replacing `ActionDispatch::Static` in the above example with `0`. See https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#common-gotchas for more information about the argument.

Comment: this should work. i use `ActionDispatch::Static` as the first argument instead of `0`.

Comment: This worked very good for me. @ReydiSutandang, Why did you suggest `ActionDispatch::Static` instead of `0`?

Comment: Now that I've worked with a new project, I've noticed that this solution makes a lot of sense for more complicated needs. I've selected it as the best answer

Comment: @ReydiSutandang Came back to this for a new project and realized that `ActionDispatch::Static ` isn't always the best answer. It's generally better than `0`, but it doesn't work for many environments (such as if you host static assets with NGINX, in which case, you wouldn't have `ActionDispatch::Static` in your production app). If you serve static assets through rails in production (which is generally a bad idea if you can avoid it), you should use `ActionDispatch::Static` instead of 0

Answer (score 7):

I was able to figure this out with a bit of help from @Akiomi's answer:

In my `routes.rb`, I added the following code to the top of the file:

```
  match '(:anything)' => 'application#nothing', via: [:options]
```

Next, in my application controller, I added:

```
def nothing
    render text: '', content_type: 'text/plain'
end
```

Along with the headers in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => 'GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:' => 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
}
```

Yes, notice the `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers:' => 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'` that was not included in my original question, this is one of the big problems.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code:

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
match 'students' => 'students#option', via: [:options]
```

In `controllers/student_controller.rb`:

```
def option
  render text: '', content_type: 'text/plain'
end
```

Or you can use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases a browser will do a preflight request: rather than actually doing the request it first does an OPTIONS request to the same url, so that it can find out what the values of the various CORS headers are (More on preflighting [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)). If this request is successful and the headers have the correct values, it then does the actual request.

You haven't added a route for these options requests, so they're going through to the rails 404 page which doesn't include the CORS headers.

The OPTIONS response just needs to set the same CORS headers as you would normally set during a request. It shouldn't do anything else. For example

```
match 'students' => 'students#cors_preflight', via: [:options]

def cors_preflight
  render nothing: true
end
```

Note that there are other CORS headers you may need to set such as `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

When you've got this working you may wish to consider tightening this up a little - you are potentially opening your app to cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: It's a public api. I knew about the 404, but that doesn't work as you haven't included headers yet. Below I have answer my question in a way that works.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```